# Rails- Cannot Load Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Anytime I hit rails server, try to start a new app, etc. I get the following error:

```
    /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-4.2.4/bin/rails (LoadError)
from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

That in itself doesn't tell me much and I'm not sure how to go about fixing this as it just started happening this morning. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least Ruby version 1.9.3 or above to use Rails 4 I believe.

Comment: When I install ruby 2.2.1, it says Already installed ruby-2.2.1.

However when I type in my command line ruby -v, it says 
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

how can this be?

Comment: @JasonBourne `rvm --default use ruby-2.2.1`, `gem install rails` and tell me what happens?

Comment: I did just that and I'm now "riding ruby on rails". Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0):

Install rails gem:

```
gem install rails
```

Comment: I just tried that and typed rails server to run again- it did not work.